# Java Spring: @Autowired (Field repository in Controller required a bean named Repository that could not be found.)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I try to connect my Java Spring app with PostgreSQL. Unfortunately I receive an error while using @Autowired: "Field repository in Controller required a bean named Repository that could not be found."

Controller.java

```js
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
 @Autowired
 private UserRepository userRepository;

 @GetMapping
 public List<User> getAllUsers() {
  return userRepository.findAll();
 }
}
```

Repository.java

```js
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    
}
```

JpaConfig.java

```js
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

}
```

pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you have any idea what's the problem here? I appreciate your help.

Comment: you forgot to add @EnableJpaRepositories in your configuration

Comment: I tried that but how do I have to configure it? Just adding "@EnableJpaRepositories" relies to the same error.

Comment: try to add the package where repositories are located or look at the documentation. You need to add it to a @Configuration class.

Comment: I changed it to "@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "group.project.repository")". The error changed to: "Field repository in Controller required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found."

Comment: well yes you need to define all the required jpa beans! You'll need a DataSource an EntityManagerFactory and a TransactionManager. I suggest that you read the documentation before going any further https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.repositories